# SQL - Invalid column name, but it exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im getting an error when trying to use inner join.

Invalid column name 'SupplierID'.

The column exists in both tables.

```sql
select p.ProductID, s.CompanyName, od.orderID
from OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB', 'Server=DESKTOP-509LB9L\MSSQLSERVER01;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
   'select ss.CompanyName from northwind.dbo.suppliers ss') s
   inner join [DESKTOP-509LB9L\MSSQLSERVER01].northwind.dbo.products p
on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
    inner join northwind.dbo.[Order Details] od
on od.ProductID = p.ProductID
    inner join northwind.dbo.Orders o
on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
```

Expected results :

```sql
ProductID    CompanyName     OrderID      UnitPrice      Quantity
1            Exotic Liquids   10249        42,40            35
2            Mayumi's         10250        35,40            10
3            Pavlova, Ltd.    10255        18,60            22
```

Comment: Your `s` table alias is an alias for a `OPENROWSET` query that only contains `CompanyName`. As such, `s.SupplierID` does not exist.

Comment: "The column exists in both tables"  But you don't `SELECT` it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select the respective column SupplierID in your sub query,

```
select p.ProductID, s.CompanyName, od.orderID
from OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB', 'Server=DESKTOP- 
509LB9L\MSSQLSERVER01;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
'select ss.CompanyName, SS.SupplierID from northwind.dbo.suppliers ss') s
inner join [DESKTOP-509LB9L\MSSQLSERVER01].northwind.dbo.products p
on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
inner join northwind.dbo.[Order Details] od
on od.ProductID = p.ProductID
inner join northwind.dbo.Orders o
on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select SupplierID in `OPENROWSET`. If you are joining two tables without selecting a columns that is why you receiving an error.

Just add `ss.SupplierID` with `ss.CompanyName` as following

```
select ss.SupplierID, ss.CompanyName from northwind.dbo.suppliers ss
```